# Prove that if A,B,C are mutually independent, the complements are independent

Tags: probability

**Suppose A,B and C are three mutually
independent events, prove A$^{c},$B$^{c}$, C$^{c}$ are also mutually
independent.**

From the definition I know P(A$\cap B\cap C)$=P(A)P(B)P(C) , I also
know
 P(A$\cap B\cap C)^{c}=1-P(A)P(B)P(C)$
and P(A)$^{c}=1-P(A)$ but I cannot see a correct manipulation to
prove the complements are independent 
using intersections or demorgans laws.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Suppose $A,B$ are independent. Then

$P(A^c \cap B^c) $

$= 1-P(A \cup B) $

$= 1-(P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B))$

$=P(A \cap B) -P(A) - P(B) +1$

$=P(A)P(B)-P(A)-P(B)+1$

$=(1-P(A))(1-P(B))$

$=P(A^c)P(B^c)$

This shows that $A^c, B^c$ are independent.

Now use a similar idea to prove the remaining, i.e. that the probability of the intersections of the following are the product of their probabilities

$B^c, C^c$

$A^c, C^c$

$A^c, B^c, C^c$

Comment: Can we assume if the three events are mutually independent, that they are pairwise independent ? .

Comment: Yeah, mutual independence implies pairwise independence. It's a "stronger" form of independence.

Comment: This article seems to differ?. http://www.engr.mun.ca/~ggeorge/MathGaz04.pdf

Comment: No it doesn't. It confirms exactly what I just said: mutual independence applies to all subsets of our desired collection of events, whereas pairwise independence only applies to those subsets consisting of pairs of events.

Comment: I was thinking something like 

P(A$^{c}\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c})=$1- P(A$\cup B\cup C)$
\begin{align*}
P(A^{c}\cap B^{c}\cap C^{c}) & =1-P(A\cup B\cup C)\\
 & =1-[P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap
\end{align*}
C)-P(B$\cap C)-P(A\cap B\cap C)$ 

Then using manipulating the fact A,B,C are independent? but now im
not sure i can assume P(A$\cap B)$= P(A).P(B) etc

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to use that. In fact, you _must_ use that. Then factor the expression (as above). The reason you can use it is that mutual independence implies pairwise independence.